# Query "SELECT * FROM .... WHERE ..." in PHP with POST request

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql

I'm trying to send a user's id from my android app and then get their information in the SQLite database on the server by using $_POST method request. Following some tutorials, I found that mysqli_query() will return an Object for the successful SELECT query. So I get the user information to read a JsonObject using Volley library in the android studio. But then, I get an error:  **Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject **. I'm a newbie to PHP and Android ( just learned it from 1 month ago), please help me!. Thanks in advance.

**Here is the code in php:**

```
<?php
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bkguardian");
 mysqli_query($connect,"SET NAME 'uft8'");
 $id = $_POST['id'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM user_lock_information WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
 $data = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
 echo json_encode($row);
?>
```

**Here is the function to get user information in adroid studio:**

```
private void getUserLockInformation(String url, final String id) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LogInActivity.this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Integer numColumn = response.length();
                    lockData = new Integer[numColumn -1];
                    String nameHandle;

                    for (int i = 0; i<=numColumn-1; i++){
                        nameHandle ="lock".concat(String.valueOf(i+1));
                        try {
                            lockData[i]= response.getInt(nameHandle);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // GET NOTIFY FOR SYSTEM ERROR, NEED TO ADD MORE ACTION.
                    Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Error system, Please report this to admin!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("AAA","error \n" +error.toString());
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("id",id);
            return param;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: Is name a synonym for names?

Comment: Uhm, i do not understand your question? There is no "name" or "names" in my code

Comment: Well, that's your code, and the word 'name' definitely appears in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "your query";
if ($data = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

    echo json_encode( $row );
    $data->free();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: associative array can not be encoded to json format

Comment: My code in php is still good until i used POST method to upload the user's id by change **$id = "fakeIdTransfer";** to **$id = $_POST['id'];**.